# awk with multiple if and replacement

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'd like to do the equivalent of this in awk (for every line, from command line):

```
items = split(',')
if items[2] >= 10:
  return items[0], items[1], 7
if 4 < items[2] < 10:
  return items[0], items[1], 2
return  items[0], items[1], 1
```

The file is in csv format, with 3 fields.

Comment: Some of the question people can guess at, but `items[:1]` is obscure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the following text as, for example, xxx.awk

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
   FS="," ; 
}{
   if ( $3 >= 10 ) {
      print $1" "$2" "7 ; 
   } else if ( 4 < $3 && $3 < 10 ) {
      print $1" "$2" "2 ;
   } else {
       print $1" "$2" "1 ;
   }
}
```

Then, run it by

```
./xxx.awk  yourCSVfile
```

Remember performing the command line: "chmod +x xxx.awk" before running.

Answer (score 0):

- split syntax is `split(i,items,",")` (split string `i` in array `items` separated by `,` )
- index start at 1
- awk do not support `a < b < c` construct
- concatenation is done by `a b`

you simply want

```
split(i,items,",")
if (items[3] >= 10)
  return items[1] items[2] 7 ;
if (4 < items[3] ) ## if item[2]>=10, code isn't reached
  return items[1] items[2] 2 ;
return  items[1] items[2] 1
```

give (input string => result)

```
11,11,11 => 11117
5,5,5 => 552
1,1,1 => 111
```